# Issue in copying a csv file to an sql table in bash environment

Tags: linux, bash

Hello everyone I have an issue in copying a `csv file` to an `sql table` created in `bash environment`

```
COPY new_reader FROM '/home/dataguy/samuel/read.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

It shows an error:

> postgres=# COPY new_reader FROM '/home/dataguy/samuel/read.csv'
>   DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER; ERROR:  value "2458151262" is out of range
>   for type integer CONTEXT:  COPY new_reader, line 2, column user_id:
>   "2458151262" postgres=#

I attached a snap shoot of the error display
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2FrH.png)

Answer (score 2):

value "2458151262" is out of range for type integer

indicates that the the number is too large for the data type.

You are using a 4 byte INTEGER that has a limit of 2,147,483,647 ( 2,458,151,262 > 2,147,483,647). Instead, change the column to a BIGINT which is an 8 byte integer and will allow bigger numbers to be stored.